# How to style each list item in unordered list without inline styling?

Tags: html, css

I have this unordered list:

```html
<div id="topmenudiv">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I access each `li` tag for styling each one separately with CSS without using inline styling?

Comment: Did you mean, styling each differently?

Comment: Can you explain you question better?

Comment: I want to sytle each li tag (item 1, item 2 ,...) each one separately

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to style each list item differently, you can use the [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child):

```css
/* First item */
li:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

/* Second item */
li:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}


/* Add additional items */
```

```html
<div id="topmenudiv">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```css
#topmenudiv ul li {

}
```

Comment: If he wanted to styling a li he could simply do 
li {} .

Your answer only matters if he cares about specificity which was not mentioned.

Comment: yes only li{} can be used. But the style will be applied to all li. Just to restrict the scope I have mentioned #topmenudiv ul li {}